# Lendo XML com Tag (Nodes) Iguais

Tags: xml, visual-basic-6

como posso efetuar a leitura de um arquivo XML via VBScript onde o arquivo possui 2 tags (Nodes) principais iguais conforme o exemplo abaixo:

Arquivo XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Primeiro details -->
<details>
  <title>aaaaaaaaa</title>
  <number>5</number>
</details>

<!-- Segundo details -->
<details>
  <title>bbbbbbbbbb</title>
  <number>6</number>
</details>
```

Estou querendo obter o conteúdo do primeiro e segundo "details" capturando o "title" e o "number", porém só consigo pegar do primeiro.

Código Atual:

```
SET objXML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
objXML.async = False
objXML.load("E:\tmp\xml.xml")

DIM root, i

SET root = objXML.documentElement
MsgBox "Numeros de TAGs (Nodes): " & root.childNodes.length

FOR i = 0 TO (root.childNodes.length)-1
  MsgBox(root.childNodes.item(i).text)
NEXT
```

Da forma como está ele ira exibir 3 (Três) mensagem...
1. "Numeros de TAGs (Nodes): 2"
2. "aaaaaaaaa"
3. "5"

Comment: Você poderia colocar o código que você tem até agora?

Comment: @carlosfigueira atualizei a postagem com o código atual, porém o arquivo XML só pode ter um details, pois se tiver dois da erro.

Comment: tu pode editar o conteúdo do arquivo: geralmente é usado assim (``<details><detail id="1"></detail><detail id="2"></detail><detail id="X"></detail>``). Assim, tu sabe que tem uma lista de detalhes e pode ler cada um sem problemas.

Comment: @mend3 infelizmente não da, pois os arquivos xml são gerados a partir de um outro software, também já pensei em fazer isso... outro porém é a quantidade de arquivos a serem alteraras que é imensa.

Answer (score -1):

```
SET objXML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
objXML.async = False

objXML.load("E:\tmp\xml.xml")

DIM root, i

SET root = objXML.documentElement
MsgBox "Numeros de TAGs (Nodes): " & root.childNodes.length

FOR i = 0 TO (root.childNodes.length)-1
  MsgBox(root.childNodes.item(i).selectSingleNode("title").nodeTypedValue)
NEXT
```

Seria isso?

root.childNodes.item(i).selectSingleNode("title").nodeTypedValue
root.childNodes.item(i).selectSingleNode("number").nodeTypedValue